# Best data type for storing microtime difference in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, datediff

I'm going to be logging the time it takes to process a REST request and I'm undecided on which data type would be best for the column. The time difference would be in the millisecond scale, where I wouldn't expect it to be less than 1ms but could be a couple seconds (certianly hope it won't be higher!).

Very similar to [Best way to store span on time in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867598/best-way-to-store-span-on-time-in-a-mysql-database), but while having a higher precision.

I believe I have two options: timestamp or integer. Timestamp has microsecond precision and integer could have any practical precision I need (would just multiply time diff by Y * 1000).

The time difference will be calculated in PHP by

```
$start = microtime(true);
// do something
$runtime = microtime(true) - $start;
```

**Which data type would be best to store a time difference on the millisecond scale in MySQL?**

**What are the pros/cons of timestamp and integer for this situation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timestamp is used to store a moment in time, not a duration of time. `TIMESTAMP` doesn't store milliseconds and neither will `TIME`. Go with an integer field.

I also found a similar question: [Storing microseconds in MySQL: which workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257331/storing-microseconds-in-mysql-which-workaround).

Comment: Since this is for profiling, I'd advise a bigint, in case a request hangs too much. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed that it won't actually store milliseconds.

Comment: Wouldn't an integer field miss some precision since microtime(true) returns a float/double ?

Answer (score 3):

Timestamp is not going to cut it.

> TIMESTAMP columns are displayed in the same format as DATETIME
>   columns. In other words, the display width is fixed at 19 characters,
>   and the format is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

Even if you do several rows to capture "moments in time" to do a delta (difference) of the two, at it's best precision would only be in seconds.

I would do it in integer. This way you can do `multipliers` on miliseconds. For example, .1 milisecond can be stored as "1" in the integer column. Because integers can only be stored in an integer column, by having a hard multiplier rule, you can work backwards to determine milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed that it won't actually store milliseconds.